# App Store Incremental EPF Data

Tags: authentication, app-store, itunes-store, itunes-app

I have to import EPF data from itunes Store daily so i have to write a script which will authenticate me firstly through the feeds url and then allow me to download the file automatically through script.

But, i am not finding any way to authenticate myself through url:

```
http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/
```

firstly i downloaded it manually but now i want my script to download it daily. How i can authenticate myself for this? Or there is any other way to achieve this?

Any ideas or view will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it through curl and now i am in it.

```
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$url = "http://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$username:$password");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, Array("Content-Type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_UNRESTRICTED_AUTH, 1);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $output;
```

it was this much simple :)

Answer (score 0):

In python you could use the `requests` [library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for example, that does Auth nicely (and you could write your download logic maybe in an easier fashion.
It would look like something like this

```
username='yourusernamehere'
password='yourpasswordhere'
response = requests.get('https://feeds.itunes.apple.com/feeds/', auth=(username, password), stream=True)
```

Note that I used the `stream=True` mechanism because you will be downloading huge files that probably will not fit in memory, you should use chunking like so:

```
 with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
        if chunk:  # filter out keep-alive new chunks
            f.write(chunk)
            f.flush()
```